# Get partial seconds difference from timestamps

Tags: java

I have a code that basically logs data, as of now everything seems to be working fine except I am having issues getting the difference between two time stamps:

```
System.out.println(readings.size());
    displayLog.appendText("Getting ready to print! Beep Boop! \n" );

            for (int t = 0; t < readings.size(); t++)
    {
        displayLog.appendText("Time: " + readings.get(t).getTimestamp() + " CH1: " + readings.get(t).getValue(0) + " CH2: " + readings.get(t).getValue(1) + " CH3: " + readings.get(t).getValue(2) + " CH4: " + readings.get(t).getValue(3) + " CH5: " + readings.get(t).getValue(4) + " CH6: " + readings.get(t).getValue(5) + " CH7: " + readings.get(t).getValue(6) + " CH8: " + readings.get(t).getValue(7) + " CH9: " + readings.get(t).getValue(8) + "\n");
    }
            int maxReading = readings.size() - 1;
            displayLog.appendText(readings.get(0).getTimestamp() + "\n");
            displayLog.appendText(readings.get(maxReading).getTimestamp() + "\n");

            Duration timeDifference = Duration.between(readings.get(0).getTimestamp(), readings.get(maxReading).getTimestamp());

            displayLog.appendText("Time difference is: " + timeDifference.getSeconds() + "\n");
```

Whenever I run the code I get an interger, is there a way to get like a double with partial seconds displayed?
Say 6.3 seconds or 8.8 seconds instead of 6 and 9. I dont even know if it rounds up or rounds down or truncates or what does it do when it returns this value? or is there a better way to get time difference?

The timestamps get logged by pressing a button using timeStamp LocalDateTime.now()

I tried this code to print and see but I get inconsisten results:

```
    int maxReading = readings.size() - 1;
    Duration timeDifference = Duration.between(readings.get(0).getTimestamp(), readings.get(maxReading).getTimestamp());
    double secondsDifference = timeDifference.getNano() / 1000000000;
    textLog.appendText("Total time logged is: " + secondsDifference + "\n");
    System.out.println(timeDifference.getSeconds() + "  |  " + secondsDifference + "  |  " + timeDifference.getNano());
    System.out.println("Time logged: " + secondsDifference);
```

However, this gives out the following output, which does not make sense (IMO):

```
4  |  0.0  |  270000000
Time logged: 0.0
```

Like, according to this it logged for 4 seconds? or for 270000000 nanoseconds?
or is it actually 4.27 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `Instant.now()`, in case you log stuff while a DST change is applied, or your computer changes time zone for whatever reason.

To get a "decimal" number of seconds, you can use:

```
Duration d = ...;
double seconds = d.toNanos() / 1e9d;
```

You can then append the result as a string, with the required number of decimals - say you want 2 decimals:

```
String twoDecimals = String.format("%.2f", seconds);
```

Comment: what does toNanos() return? I mean assuming the overall duration is 6.4 seconds, will that get me 6400000000 ? and If i want to use that for other calculations? do i then parse it to double? isnt that like inefficient? (to string then to double)

Comment: Yes, 6.4 seconds, in nanoseconds. If you use it for other calculations then use the double, not the string. I just started from your code example.

Comment: Note that getSeconds returns the "seconds" part of the duration, i.e. it's truncated.

Comment: I modified the code a little and im getting some inconsistencies, please look at OP.

Comment: @DavidBoydston In your example you have used `getNanos` instead of `toNanos`. A Duration is a number of seconds plus a number of nanos. In your example 4 seconds (getSeconds) and 270000000 nanos (getNanos) so the total duration is 4.27 seconds, which you can obtain with toNanos.